# Jquery: post data to a jsp method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post

I am currently a asp.net guy, but have to do some jsp work now. I know that in asp.net, you can define a public static method with `[WebMethod]` attribute e.g.

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetIt(string code)
  {
    return GetSomething(code);
  }
```

then, I can call this method in jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/GetIt",
  data: "{'code':'+$("#code").val()+"'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

can someone give me some light how to do it using jsp?

Comment: JSP is a page-layout framework, not a controller framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure jsp and servlets you'll have to do a lot of things to achieve that.

It can easily be done with [spring-mvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), almost in the same way you showed:

- create a class and annotate it with `@Controller`
- create the method to be like this:

  ```
  @RequestMapping("/path/get")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getIt() {
      ...
  }
  ```
- you'll need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and jackson on your classpath.

Note that you are calling "get", so the logical http method is GET, rather than POST